# How to generate new credentials before exipiry of the service principal secret

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

Hi I want to auto generate client secret for service principal before the current client secret expires automatically what would be the best approach for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Graph API to do this, just try the request below:

**Request URL:**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications/<app_object_id>/addPassword
```

**Request Body**

```
{
    "passwordCredential": {
        "displayName": "<secret name>",
        "endDateTime": "2023-04-20T08:49:57.334Z",
        "startDateTime": "2021-04-20T08:50:07.909Z"
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Actually i want it to be automated that is when it is about to expire it sutomatically creates a new secret. I saw somewhere with event grid and azure function we can but i am not sure how to do

Comment: @ashish Yes, you can use Azure function with time trigger to call graph API to see if there is any secret about to expire for example check it each 10 days. And if there is some secret about to expire(for example, expires after 10 days) you create a new one. You can find Azure functon time trigger guide here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

Comment: @ashish if you are afraid of secret expiring ,you can just create a secret with a long vaild time, i,e 10 years (endDateTime - startDateTime)

Comment: @ashish,how's going? Do you have any more questions pls ?